# Deriving a simpler expression for $\left({I}-T\otimes T\right)^{-1}\left(T\otimes T\right)$ using Kronecker product properties

Tags: matrices, kronecker-product

Let $T\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$.

Is there a simpler expression for $$\left(I_{n^{2}}-T\otimes T\right)^{-1}\left(T\otimes T\right)~?$$

---

When $T$ is symmetric PSD, we could do use the unitary decomposition as in [this question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/296705/inversion-of-the-sum-of-an-identity-matrix-and-two-kronecker-products), but I am interested in a **general** square $T$.

Comment: The best you can do for general $T$ is probably to apply the Jordan-Normal-Form.

Answer (score 1):

In general, if $M$ is invertible:

$$(I-M)^{-1}M=(M(M^{-1}-I))^{-1}M=(M^{-1}-I)^{-1}M^{-1}M=(M^{-1}-I)^{-1}$$

giving here the alternative form, in the case $T$ (therefore $T \otimes T$) is invertible:

$$\left(\left(T\otimes T\right)^{-1} -I_{n^{2}}\right)^{-1}$$

with $\left(T\otimes T\right)^{-1}=T^{-1} \otimes T^{-1}.$

Is it really "simpler" ? It certainly depends on the use you will have of this expression.

Comment: It seems you're assuming $T$ is invertible here which it need not be in the question.

Comment: @Rammus Good remark. I must add in my answer.

Comment: Thank you @JeanMarie. It's helpful but I am *more* interested in non-invertible $T$s.